# Python Numpy nanmax() returning nan when there are non nan values in the array

Tags: python, numpy

I tried to use Numpy's nanmax function to get the max of all non-nan values in a matrix's column, for some it works, for some it returns nan as the maximum. However, there are non-nan values in every column and just to be sure I tried the same thing in R with max(x, na.rm = T) and everything is fine there.

Anyone has any ideas of why this occurs? The only thing I can think of is that I converted the numpy matrix from a pandas frame but I really have no clue...

```
np.nanmax(datamatrix, axis=0)

matrix([[1, 101, 193, 1, 163.0, 10.6, nan, 4.7, 142.0, 0.47, 595.0,
         170.0, 5.73, 24.0, 27.0, 23.0, 361.0, 33.0, 94.0, 9.2, 16.8, nan,
         nan, 91.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, 0.0, 105.0, nan, nan, nan, nan,nan,
         nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
         nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: show a sample matrix, and the results.

Comment: Unless you post both a minimal matrix that shows your result and the code that is causing the problem, there is nothing much we can do. This question is extremely vague as it stands.

Comment: This thread nicely illustrates the examples requested by the first two commenters:

http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `nanmax()` might not correctly handle an object array.  If `x` is the array, check `x.dtype`.  Pandas uses object arrays, so your array might also be an object array if you converted from a Pandas DataFrame.

Comment: For example, `np.nanmax(np.array([2.0, np.nan, np.nan]))` returns 2.0 as expected, but `np.nanmax(np.array([2.0, np.nan, np.nan], dtype=object))` generates a warning and returns `nan`.

Comment: Sorry for the vague description. The object array is the problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  It confirms my suspicion that your array is an object array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your array is an `object` array, meaning the elements in the array are arbitrary python objects.  Pandas uses object arrays, so it is likely that when you converted your Pandas DataFrame to a numpy array, the result was an object array.  `nanmax()` doesn't handle object arrays correctly.

Here are a couple examples, one using a `numpy.matrix` and one a `numpy.ndarray`.  With a `matrix`, you get no warning at all the something went wrong:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: m = np.matrix([[2.0, np.nan, np.nan]], dtype=object)

In [3]: np.nanmax(m)
Out[3]: nan
```

With an array, you get a cryptic warning, but `nan` is still returned:

```
In [4]: a = np.array([[2.0, np.nan, np.nan]], dtype=object)

In [5]: np.nanmax(a)
/Users/warren/miniconda3scipy/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/nanfunctions.py:326: RuntimeWarning: All-NaN slice encountered
  warnings.warn("All-NaN slice encountered", RuntimeWarning)
Out[5]: nan
```

You can determine if your array is an object array in a few ways.  When you display the array in an interactive python or ipython shell, you'll see `dtype=object`. Or you can check `a.dtype`; if `a` is an object array, you'll see either `dtype('O')` or `object` (depending on whether you end up seeing the `str()` or `repr()` of the dtype).

Assuming all the values in the array are, in fact, floating point values, a way to work around this is to first convert from the object array to an array of floating point values:

```
In [6]: b = a.astype(np.float64)

In [7]: b
Out[7]: array([[  2.,  nan,  nan]])

In [8]: np.nanmax(b)
Out[8]: 2.0

In [9]: n = m.astype(np.float64)

In [10]: np.nanmax(n)
Out[10]: 2.0
```