# why numpy max function(np.max) return wrong output?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have `pandas DataFrame` and I turn it to `numpy ndarray`.I use `max` function for one column in my DataFrame like this:

```
print('column: ',df[:,3])
print('max: ',np.max(df[:,3]))
```

And the output was:

```
column: [0.6559999999999999 0.48200000000000004 0.9990000000000001 ..., 1.64 nan 0.07]
max: 0.07
```

But as you can see for example first value is greater than  0.07!!
What is the problem?

Comment: Can you maybe store the df[:,3] into a separate dataframe and find its max? For me, it seems to be working

Comment: I do that but it still don't work

Comment: Can you point me to the entire df, if possible?

Comment: whole of it or just third column?

Comment: Yeah, 3 column will also do fine, basically minimum data for me to reproduce this on my end.

Comment: Are you sure that you are properly making an array from dataframe?
np.max(df.values[:,3])

Comment: in my code df is df.values

Comment: If you can show a small and complete sample of your code, it will be easier to debug.

Comment: Hm. Ok, that starts to be interesting... Can you please provide a minimum reproducible example, since I am unable to reproduce the example you provided.

Comment: You also can use df.iloc[3].max() to substitute using numpys function if that suits your needs.

Comment: I don't know how to upload data to be usable for you because my dataframe has 119400 row and 7 column

Comment: @StasBuzuluk your suggestion works fine. thanks

Comment: but I have another question. why np.nanmax don't work too?

Comment: Check the chat, please :)

Comment: I've edited my answer so it should suits better. 
If you want to read more about converting columns data types: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891038/change-data-type-of-columns-in-pandas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### There are two problems here

---

1. It looks like **column you are trying to find maximum for has the data type `object`**. It's not recommended if you are sure that your column should contain numerical data since it may cause unpredictable behaviour not only in this particular case. Please check data types for your dataframe(you can do this by typing `df.dtypes`) and change it so that it corresponds to data you expect(for this case `df[column_name].astype(np.float64)`). [This is also the reason for `np.nanmax` not working properly.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39024791/python-numpy-nanmax-returning-nan-when-there-are-non-nan-values-in-the-array)
2. You don't want to use `np.max` on arrays, containing nans.

### Solution

---

1. If you are sure about having `object` data type of column:

   1.1. You can use the max method of Series, it should cast data to float automatically.

   `df.iloc[3].max()`

   1.2. You can cast data to propper type only for nanmax function.

   `np.nanmax(df.values[:,3].astype(np.float64)`

   1.3 You can drop all nan's from dataframe and find max[not recommended]:

   ```
   np.max(test_data[column_name].dropna().values)
   ```

2. If type of your data is float64 and it shouldn't be `object` data type [recommended]:

   ```
   df[column_name] = df[column_name].astype(np.float64)

   np.nanmax(df.values[:,3])
   ```

### Code to illustrate problem

---

```
#python
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

test_data = pd.DataFrame({
                   'objects_column': np.array([0.7,0.5,1.0,1.64,np.nan,0.07]).astype(object),
                   'floats_column': np.array([0.7,0.5,1.0,1.64,np.nan,0.07]).astype(np.float64)})

print("********Using np.max function********")
print("Max of objects array:", np.max(test_data['objects_column'].values))
print("Max of floats array:", np.max(test_data['floats_column'].values))

print("\n********Using max method of series function********")
print("Max of objects array:", test_data["objects_column"].max()) 
print("Max of floats array:", test_data["objects_column"].max())
```

Returns:

```
********Using np.max function********
Max of objects array: 0.07
Max of floats array: nan

********Using max method of series function********
Max of objects array: 1.64
Max of floats array: 1.64
```

Answer (score 1):

np.max is an alias for the function np.amax which according to documentation doesn't play well with NaN values. In order to ignore NaN values you should use np.nanmax instead

Comment: That's a good assumption but not a correct answer. It looks like a real problem was related to an improper data type. As specified in numpy.amax documentation in case if there's nan in array - amax returns nan, which is not the case in this situation. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.amax.html

Comment: There's a discussion that extends question a little bit:
https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220618/discussion-between-mohammad-sadra-sharifzadeh-and-stas-buzuluk